# Factoring commutative coefficients to the left

Tags: ncalgebra

Is it possible to make ncalgebra factorize commutative coefficients **to the left**?

For example, if I define a non-commutative object `W` and a commutative object `a` by

```
SetNonCommutative[W];
SetCommutative[a];
```

and then write

```
a W
```

the output is, as expected, just `a W`. Same for

```
W a
```

However, if I write

```
a[t] W
```

instead, for some reason `a[t]` lands on the right and the output is

```
W a[t]
```

Even if I apply `Simplify` to the latter, it still remains the same.

Finally, if I write

```
a[t] W + a[t] tp[W] // Simplify
```

then the output looks as I would want it to:

```
a[t] (W + tp[W])
```

I found two similar questions on the forum, but the approach with `NCCollect` doesn't work here.

---

Here's a more real life example:
[image]
The commutative expression in `a` in the second parentheses got factored out to the left, but not the expression in the first.

By the way, the `LeafCount` of the expression factored as I want it to be is one less than the `LeafCount` of the output.

---

P.S. I found the following approach to my real life example:
[image]
First, it feels more like a kludge than a solution, but it does the job. Secondly, the commutative factor is still not on the left, but at least the formula it's taken out.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what you want to do here but be careful. Even though you set `a` to be commutative, `a[t]` is still non commutative. This is because `t`, which is a small letter is still non commutative. If you set `a` and `t` to be commutative then `a[t]` would be treated as commutative. The way you have it now you have a commutative product (`Times`) of two non commutative expressions `a[t]` and `W`, and that is bound to cause you trouble, such as things don't *factor* as you would expect.

Regarding the ordering in `a[t] W`, this is controller by `Times`, which is commutative and sorted. There is nothing you can do about that.